# trouble calling methods in main? simple Client/server

Tags: java, networking, server, client

NOTE: *My First StackOverFlow POST! WHOOOP!*

Hello all, So I built a simple client server program that just takes in a string and then returns it, but for some reason I can't get my main to call the methods properly and I don't understand why it wont work. Can someone please take a look and tell me what I am missing/doing wrong. I know my logic for the networking is solid but not the calls. I think its time for fresh eyes, anything helps! Thank you.

MAIN:

```
public class FileRetrieve_Easy_main 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {    
       new Thread(new SimpleServer()).start();
       new Thread(new SimpleClient()).start();

  }
}
```

CLIENT:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    public class Client 
    {
        public static class SimpleClient implements Runnable 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                Socket socket = null;
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    socket = new Socket("localhost", 3333);
                PrintWriter outWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                outWriter.println("Hello Mr. Server!");

            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } 
            catch (UnknownHostException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                try 
                {
                    socket.close();

                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

           }
     }// end run 

       }//end simple client

    }
```

SERVER:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class Server 
    {
        public static class SimpleServer implements Runnable 
        {
            @Override
            public void run()   
            {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
                while (true) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3333);
                        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();    
                        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                        System.out.println("Client said :"+inputReader.readLine());
                     } 
                     catch (IOException e) 
                     {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     finally
                     {
                        try 
                        {
                            serverSocket.close();

                        } 
                        catch (IOException e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }//end while
            }// end run

        }//end simple server

    }//end class
```

Comment: You didn't show the import statements.  What is the error message?  And why did you make them inner classes?  Did you try new Client.SimpleClient() and new Server.SimpleServer()?  Or make them top level classes.

Comment: I don't have any imports for the main (although i trying importing the server and client classes already and it did not work). The error for both lines in the main are "SimpleServer can not be resolved to a type" and "SimpleClient can not be resolved to a type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all classes in the default package?

What if you do this:

```
public class FileRetrieve_Easy_main 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {    
       new Thread(new Server.SimpleServer()).start();
       new Thread(new Client.SimpleClient()).start();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of your server Runnable is Server.SimpleServer. And the name of your client Runnable is Client.SimpleClient.  You made them nested classes, which you can read about here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html